# Power bi mysql fatal error encountered during data read

Tags: mysql, powerbi, connection, powerbi-desktop, read-data

Do power Bi has some limits of reading a Data from mysql database? I am using a query that for a month give me sth like 700.000 rows with no big problems. When I am trying to get period of half year(it is around 4 millions rows) I got error "mysql fatal error encountered during data read". Is this because of my PC hardware and I need for example more RAM to deal with this huge amount of data?

Comment: Unless you can coax some more meaningful error message out of power bi, we can only speculate as to what could have gone wrong! In this form the question is not for programmers, but for microsoft support, I'm afraid!

Comment: It has probably nothing to do with RAM, because that would give you an error containing something like 'no more memory'. But that happens almost never. Your dataset being too large would be strange too, since I have datasets containing more than 100mil rows (However, now that I think about it, they come from a datawarehouse through directquery).

Comment: I do not know what more I can say to specify this error. Query works correct but when I want to read more data there are an error and that's it. Maybe I should write message to support, thanks